# QTCreator changing permissions of files

Tags: qt-creator

So I am trying to use Qtcreator on ubuntu 18.04 and am starting to wonder if i should just return to visual studio. When I run QtCreator now it is changing permissions of various .Cpp files aswel as files in my .config folder. I assume it is not good practice to run QtCreator as superuser, so there must be some alternative solution. I have never experienced this on any other system where I setup QtCreator so Im wondering what has changed now? Any hints in the right direction are greatly appreciated. I've never had so many configuration problems with any IDE before, has something being 'upgraded' in recent versions of either Ubuntu or Qt??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running QtCreator as root?

Then indeed, every time you save some files permissions will change.

If you are running the QtCreator shipped with the SDK, and not the one from the packages, I presume you installed it in /opt

Also, QtCreator stores its configuration inside one .config subdirectory, which will again be chowned to root if you run QtCreator as root.

My suggestion:

```
1 - chown the ~/.config dir recursively back to your user
2 - chown the sources
3 - run QtCreator without sudo / su
```

If you can't run QtCreator as your normal user, then maybe there's a problem with your SDK installation. To ensure you have rw access to the SDK you can run the SDK installer without sudo and install everything to a subdirectory of your home directory instead of /opt.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up to this question, the QtCreator seems to lock its config files when it is starting up, and if anything goes wrong on startup, these files are trapped in some locked state. Best course of action is to restart QtCreator exactly as normal, this will resolve the locking issue usually, but sometimes you have to restart the whole system, depending on the severity of the startup problem. Dont do as I did and try to chown/chmod the files, your only digging deeper.